# How to restrict commands in Azure Cache for Redis

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

Redis Cache allows [to disable, rename possibly harmful commands](https://redis.io/topics/security#disabling-of-specific-commands) FLUSHALL, FLUSHDB, etc.

We use Azure Cache for Redis where:

- You cannot change all settings, because [config is managed by
  Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#redis-commands-not-supported-in-azure-cache-for-redis)
- You do not have a direct access to redis.conf: [only via Azure Portal
  or via shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#default-redis-server-configuration) but for the same set of settings.
- Not all [commands are supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#redis-commands-not-supported-in-azure-cache-for-redis) like CONFIG, SAVE, ACL, etc
- [ACL feature](https://redis.io/topics/acl) is not supported in [Azure Cache for Redis 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-version#what-features-arent-supported-with-redis-6)

**The problem:**

The same Redis Db is used by many apps using different key prefixes. Anyone can connect to that Redis Db (ex: dev env) via some UI Client and accidentally execute FLUSHALL and erase all data.
And we even do not know who it was.

**Question:**

Is their a possibility to restrict, disable, rename FLUSHALL command to prevent accidental usage?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to restrict, disable, rename FLUSHALL command to prevent accidental usage?

You can disable commands in  Redis Cache or can rename them like FLUSHALL, FLUSHDB etc.

But it is not possible in Azure Redis Cache to restrict, disable, rename **FLUSHALL** command to prevent accidental usage.